# Problems getting an 1px border on a table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot of combinations but I can't seem to get just a simple 1px border on all the cells and surrounding of a table. Here's what I have:

```
table.admin    { border-collapse:collapse; }
table.admin,
table.admin td,
table.admin th { border: 1px solid #BBB; padding: 5px; }
table.admin td { text-align:left; }
table.admin th {background-color: #BBB; font-weight: 400; }

<table class="admin">
    <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Row</th><th>Row</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td><td>abc</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>abc</td><td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It looks really simple BUT what I get is a table where every row has a bottom border of 2px.

I tried this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJyCq/) It looks fine there but not on my page. I am totally confused as there is still this 2px border on the bottom of every row. I just can't see why.

Does anyone have any suggestions? All I want is to see the cells with a nice 1px border that looks the same around every cell. Please note that it looks good in fiddle so why not in my Firefox browser :-(

Here's another example. I just added to my page. I used a different class name so I could be sure there was nothing inherited from another place:

```
<style>
table.admin2    { border-collapse:collapse; }
table.admin2,
table.admin2 td,
table.admin2 th { border: 1px solid #BBB; padding: 5px; }
table.admin2 td { text-align:left; }
table.admin2 th {background-color: #BBB; font-weight: 400; }
</style>
<table class="admin2">
    <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Row</th><th>Row</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td><td>abc</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>abc</td><td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note: After comments by Spudley I checked other browsers and this only happens with Firefox. I am using Firefox 4.  Not sure how to solve but at least I see it only with one browser.

Comment: Include your entire HTML page, please. The mark-up and CSS is fine and renders what you'd expect on Chrome, Firefox 4 and IE9. I'm guessing that you have some invalid mark-up somewhere.

Comment: Just added the HTML. Are you trying with fiddle?

Comment: Change  border: 1px solid #BBB  to  border: 1px solid black It make the border visible, and around all of the elements.

Comment: You might just be better off using `cellspacing` on your table instead of giving the `<th>` element a border.

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing with -- this reminds me of a bug I saw in Firefox where the bottom border was coming out too thick for no apparent reason. The same code worked in all other browsers, and even Firebug reported the correct size for the border, so we gave up and decided it must just be a bug in the browser.

Comment: Now i have 2px wide black horizontal borders and all vertical borders are 1px. I am using firefox.

Comment: I've included your `another example` simply in a HTML file (without doctype). It looks fine on Firefox and Chrome. Please describe your problem in greater detail, it should work fine.

Comment: Wow I just tried in IE and Opera and it's okay. I guess it's the bug that Spudley mentioned !!!   Now I wonder how to solve it for Firefox .

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised to not see this in the fiddle (using FF4), but here's what I think you *may* be seeing:

Since every cell has a border, naturally in between rows you will see it "doubled", when it's actually the top and bottom border of the two cells combined, or combined with the border of the table itself for the first and last rows.

Try using something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/dJyCq/1/):

```
table, th, td {
    border:1px solid #BBB;
}
table {
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:0;
}
td, th {
    border-top:0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

Hope I've understood your problem correctly, I seem to remember having to do this before.

Comment: This almost worked. I added border-collapse:collapse; to table but things still look quite odd :-(

Comment: I'm actually baffled by this, I don't seem to remember table cell borders behaving so nicely as they are in your demo, I always remembered having to eliminate the border-width like this... Can you provide a link to your actual work, not in a fiddle? And which version of which browser are you seeing it in?

Comment: My code is not in production so I can't provide a link. I started to do more research and it seems there's quite a lot of others with similar problems with firefox. I am trying different solutions now. Seems firefox doesn't much like border-collapse and works a bit different from other browsers. I am seeing the problem in Firefox 4

Comment: Tell me, do you see the issue [here](http://wesleymurch.com/test/table-1.html)? This is copy/paste from your fiddle and I don't see it in FF4. Are you sure that it's not being inherited from some other CSS rule?

Comment: I also don't see this in FF4. I checked with firebug and could not see any of the table elements inheriting anything other than from body.

Comment: So... how can this be reproduced then?

Comment: I will spend time looking into this more. I already removed all the CSS links. The pages looks a complete mess but at the bottom I still see the table with the borders not looking right. I do reference jQuery but can't see how that could be doing anything and I will take that and all other surrounding code out.

Answer (score 6):

Just put the border color you want as background-color in the table, a different color as background-color in the td elements and define a border-spacing of 1px, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JcbLd/1/